# Electrical switch installation

Tags: wiring

My 2-way light switch doesn't work.  I need to replace it but all I have on hand is a 3-way.  How do I wire it to function as a 2-way?

Comment: I'm not even sure if that is code.. Wouldn't it just be easier to run down to the hardware store and get a proper switch?

Comment: It would.  But I am handicapped and this is what I have on hand.

Answer (score 3):

A 3-way switch connects the common (hot) alternately to each of two *travelers* as it is switched. You can connect one of the wires from the old switch to the common terminal on the 3-way, and the other to one of the traveler terminals, leaving the other traveler terminal unconnected. There should be a marking on the side or back of the 3-way indicating which terminal is the common.

Code requires that *up* is *on* for an unmarked switch. A 3-way is unmarked. Hook it up and see if *up* is *on*. If not, shift the wire from the connected traveler terminal to the other traveler terminal.